# Building docker image on Minikube: Getting error: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection

Tags: docker, minikube

I have setup a minikube cluster on Windows 10 using "hyperv" Virtual Machine driver.

Now, I want to build docker images on minikube. When I try to pull an image from docker hub, I am getting the error as shown in the screenshot:

> C:\Users\sudhindra.kulkarni\Documents\Technical>docker build . -t
>   mysql:0.0.1 Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB Step 1/6 :
>   FROM mysql:5.7
>   **Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers)**

I did search for the solution and accordingly, modified the DNS Network settings in Docker Desktop to "Fixed", restarted the Docker Desktop as well.

However, the problem hasn't got fixed.  My minikube Hyper-V VM is using "BusyBox" binary and it is not using any distribution. So, I am not able to install any packages for fixing the issue as well.

***1. Please help me in finding the solution for this issue

2. How to install packages in Linux VM with "BusyBox" binary.***

Comment: Are you trying to build a docker image using docker for windows or using minikube ssh console? Are you behind a proxy? Did you try to pull some image from docker hub?

Comment: Hi @mWatney, I am trying to build the docker image through minikube ssh console. It's a busybox binary image.   Yesterday, I did add a Virtual switch to connect to External networks (through Wireless network adapter) and modified the minikube VM settings to set the same switch as the "network adapter".  However, I am still not able to get this issue fixed.  I am not able to even pull the docker image from my local registry.  Please help.

Comment: The network was working before you change this settings in VM? You can try to use minikube delete to reset you minikube installation. In minikube ssh console you are able to test if you network is configured correctly and can reach your destination using ping or curl command, If it doesn't work you need to revise you network settings. This minikube VM is not intended to be used as you are doing. So I would highly recommend you to create a separate VM for that purpose.

Comment: Hi @mWatney,  I was able to curl to google without any issues inside my minikube VM. However, I am not able to connect either connect to Docker hub or to my local registry. If I am able to curl to google, then I should be able to connect to docker hub right ? Please let me know as to how to proceed further on this.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your setup, because in the main question you posted an error building a docker image using Windows terminal, but in comments you said you tried to do it inside minikube console. What do you want  to achieve, pull images from docker hub or pull images from your local repository? I tested in my minikube installation and I'm able to pull images from Docker Hub.

Comment: To use private registry, try [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon). Try to pull some public image from docker hub inside your minikube console and post the error. make sure you don't have any firewall blocking your connections. Please update your question with this details.